# Main UI thread waits other thread's finish

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app I have to show some images. They are stored on device localy. However, if some pictures aren't saved on device, they should be downloaded from web.
The thing is that I must show downloading animation (for example, simple circle progressbar, just spinning animation, or simple picture), and when download is finished, just reload view that contains pictures. So I have following code in UI thread:

```
if(notDownloaded)
{
    Methods.downloadFile(fileparams);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.downloading);
    listOfPictures.add(iv);
}
```

`Methods.downloadFile()`

```
public static void downloadFile(DCFile _dcFile, Context _context) {

    final DCFile dcFile = _dcFile;
    final Context context = _context;

    Thread thread = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){

            String response = "";
            try {
                Download download = new Download();
                response = download.execute(dcFile,context).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(response.equals("OK"))
            {
                downloadFinished.onDownloadFinished(); //interface-event
            }
        }
    };

    thread.run();
}
```

`onDownloadFinished` refreshes pictures view.
Class `Download`:

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    DCFile dcFile = (DCFile) params[0];
    Context context = (Context) params[1];
    try {
        URL url = new URL(dcFile.getPath() + dcFile.getFileName());
        File file;
        if(dcFile.getType() == 0)
        {
            File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "pics/");
            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "pics/" + dcFile.getUid());
        }
        else
        {
            File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "voices/");
            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "voices/" + dcFile.getUid());
        }
        if(file.exists())
            return "";

        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file, 5000, 10000);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

}

So if some pics are missed, I should have seen `R.drawable.downloading`, and then, when pic is downloaded, I shold have seen that picture.
However, I see just black screen when picture is downloading, and then that picture.
So I realized that UI thread waits when picture downloading is finished.

How to resolve this thing? And where's the mistake?

Comment: That's definitely lack of code, you should include any related code block including the `downloadFile()` and update part.

Comment: @nKn I've edited post, check it please